# python bytes array display is different to element value

Tags: python

I have a bytes array returned from a hardware module,
the len is:

```
len(a)
51
```

when I display it in vscode or terminal, it shows:

> b'>128 143 134 135 141 139 134 120 137 135 132 143 \r\n'

when I try to convert it to list:

```
     s = list(a.strip())
s[0]
62
s[1]
49
s[2]
50
s[3]
56
```

how could I convert list s to 12 integers shown in vscode or terminal?

Comment: I think you want `a.split()` not `a.strip()`

Comment: those integers you are getting are the ascii codes of the characters: `ord(">") == 62 and ord("1") == 49` etc.

Comment: a.split() will get [b'>128',b'143',.....]

Comment: @adameye2020 correct there are other characters that you will need to remove from the string. Plenty of resource out there on how to do that.

Comment: oh, I guess when i use readline() functon, it reads '>' for the first line, '>' is from the terminal output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a `bytes` string. You could use `strip` to get rid of the  `\r\n` on the end, then slice `1:` to get rid of the `>` at the front. Then, split on spaces to get a list of strings and convert those to integers.

```
test = b'>128 143 134 135 141 139 134 120 137 135 132 143 \r\n'
l = [int(val) for val in a.strip()[1:].split(b" ")]
print(l)
```

output

```
[128, 143, 134, 135, 141, 139, 134, 120, 137, 135, 132, 143]
```

Answer (score 0):

I went for a regex that looks for number-like things:

```
import re

b = b'>128 143 134 135 141 139 134 120 137 135 132 143 \r\n'

l = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str(b))]
```